# What is the difference between Gnome Compiz Flashback and Gnome Metacity Flashback?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, graphics, 14.04, metacity

I upgrade ubuntu 13.10 from the development branch (alpha version or beta version) and after that at login user only two options are available. here I am attaching an image of gnome metacity

[image: screenshot of Gnome metacity]

1. **Gnome Compiz flashback**
2. **Gnome Metacity flashback**

What are these versions of Gnome and I would like to know what is the difference?

---

for how to get back ubuntu default I asked here another question and here is a link for that 
[same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457270/user-login-screen-shows-only-gnome-flashback-option-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The backend is different: Compiz uses a 3D compositor to display the windows. Whereas Metacity displays the windows in 2D. So if you have a low end graphics card and/or want to save energy on a mobile device I would suggest that you use metacity.

There also used to be problems with 3D applications in combination with compiz.

Comment: i attach image.graphics problem occurs on mouse curser when i type something. and please can i get more info of about these.

Comment: these two option only appears in user login. so how enable or open default ubuntu.

Comment: Probably a bug. I would suggest that you use the metacity compositor.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience falling back to gnome after installing Trusty, these answers are not fully adequate. I found the Metacity option preferable to the compiz for two reasons right out of the box. Metacity comes set up with four workspaces, while this has to be configured in compiz and I found the configuration not straightforward as apparently there are two competing window managers. Further Metacity will consistently put the menus on the panel where I expect them whereas the compiz version did not always do this.

Comment: Yes I know what UI differences exist between compiz and metacity. Still thanks for sharing your experience :)