# User login screen shows only gnome flashback option in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

Hello i upgrade ubuntu 13.10 development branch and successfully installed ubuntu 14.04. but my problem is on user login screen.User login screen shows only gnome flashback option so how to get back ubuntu default. may be this is bug but how to get back ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using Ubuntu ..        .

Comment: Probably because your question is very unclear. We can't see your screen so you need to be much more specific than "only gnome-flashback option". Did you install gnome? How did you upgrade? What was the last desktop environment you logged into? etc.

Comment: Last desktop environment was ubuntu 13.10 (develpoment branch called as aplha or beta version of ubuntu). and i did not install gnome . I just upgrade Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: and i report bug at launchpad . see the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1314360)

Comment: @Seth tell me if you need more specification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 thn try following, might helps you.

Try to check whether ubuntu-desktop is installed or not !

If its not installed, Try to Install Ubuntu Desktop package

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Hope this will helps you.